# Display lightbox image retrieved from longblob database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, image, fancybox

I'm using the lightbox plugin: [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)

I wanted to apply lightbox effect on image gallery php file. The image is stored in longblob format instead of folder. Following is the code I did to read image.

```
<?php 
    $img_slct=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news_gallery WHERE news_id='$page[news_id]' ORDER BY position ASC"); 

    while($img=mysql_fetch_array($img_slct))
    { ?>
        <img src="load_image.php?id=<?php echo $img['file_id']; ?>"/>
<?php } ?>
```

load_image.php

```
  $id=$_GET['id']; 
  $is_file=false;

  if(!empty($id))
  {
      $file=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM news_files WHERE id='$id'");

      if(mysql_num_rows($file)>0)
      {
         $is_file=true;
         $file=mysql_fetch_array($file);    
      }
  }

  if($is_file)
      display_file_news($id);
```

Everything is displayed correctly but that is an issue when using lightbox to display the image retrieved from longblob database.

```
<a rel="example_group" href="load_image.php?id=<?php echo $img['file_id']; ?>">
    <img src="load_image.php?id=<?php echo $img['file_id']; ?>"/>
</a>
```

I have no idea how to read the longblob database using lightbox. So I simply put like this --> `href="load_image.php?id=<?php echo $img['file_id']; ?>"`

I know that is wrong, but can you help me? Please...Let me know if you need more info, because I can't insert all my code at here. Thank you.

Following are my database tables.

news_files table

[image: news_gallery]

news_gallery table

[image: news_files]

Comment: are you trying to display an image from your database? because it would be better to store your images on a location in your database, and store the url of that location into your database, and then display the image with the url

Comment: yes, I stored the URL into database. I have updated the database info as shown above, `news_gallery` table is used to connect the data between `news` table and `news_files` table.

Comment: I have solved it, thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Hi @Eelyn, how did you solve it? I'm currently not able to use php viewing with lightbox plugin (fancyapps.com one).

Comment: Are you using the same method as me? Using the URL `load_image.php?id=` to read the image from database.